# react render zindex style only when it is set to zero

Tags: html, css, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jsx

I need to set a dynamic z-index for my components based on the state variables. **But it is working only when zindex is set 0** .

My array is a below

```
images:[
                                    ['img1',false,[1,2,3],1,0],//4th one is zindex
                                    ['img2',false,[2,3,1],2,0],
                                    ['img3',false,[4,5],3,10],
                                    ['img4',false,[1,2,3],4,0],
                                    ['img5',false,[2,3,1],5,0],
                                    ['img6',false,[5],6,0],
                                    ['img7',false,[1,2,3],7,0],
                                    ['img8',false,[2,3,1],8,0],
                                    ['img9',false,[5],9,0],
                                    ['img10',false,[1,2,3],10,0],
                                    ['img11',false,[2],11,10],
                                    ['img12',false,[5],12,10]
                              ],
```

jsx snippet

```
{this.state.images.map((im,index) =>
                                    <div className="img-block" style={{'z-index':im[4]}}  draggable="true" onDragStart={this.drag.bind(this,im[3],index)} onDrop={this.drop.bind(this,im[3],index)} onDragOver={this.allowDrop}>
)}
```

Rendered HTML Output

```
<div class="img-block" draggable="true" style="z-index: 0;">
<div class="img-block" draggable="true" style="z-index: 0;">
<div class="img-block" draggable="true"> //not rendered 10
<div class="img-block" draggable="true" style="z-index: 0;">
<div class="img-block" draggable="true" style="z-index: 0;">
<div class="img-block" draggable="true" style="z-index: 0;">
<div class="img-block" draggable="true" style="z-index: 0;">
<div class="img-block" draggable="true" style="z-index: 0;">
<div class="img-block" draggable="true" style="z-index: 0;">
<div class="img-block" draggable="true" style="z-index: 0;">
<div class="img-block" draggable="true" > //not rendered 10
<div class="img-block" draggable="true" > //not rendered 10
```

Please let me know what I missed here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried [running your code in jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/reactjs/69z2wepo/) and got the error

[image]

After renaming `z-index` to `zIndex` all elements have been assigned one.